# iOS Core ML and a DBSCAN Python scikit model

Tags: ios, machine-learning, scikit-learn, cluster-analysis, coreml

I'm trying to create a DBSCAN machine learning model using the scikit. So far i have somehow working Python model.

After this i want to convert it into a Core ML model, to be able to use it inside my iPhone application.

I read a lot of info. And [here](https://www.analyticsvidhya.com/blog/2017/09/build-machine-learning-iphone-apple-coreml/) i found something like:

**Core ML Only supports regression & classification (clustering, ranking, dimensionality reduction, etc. are not supported)**

DBSCAN is a clustering algorithm, so according to this, even if i will successfully create my Python Machine learning model, i won't be able to convert it to Core ML, and to use inside my application?

Comment: Core ML is too limited. Don't use it.

Comment: What scikit-learn methods are you using?

Comment: I'm based on this http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/cluster/plot_dbscan.html#sphx-glr-auto-examples-cluster-plot-dbscan-py

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer is **no**.

Long answer: CoreML is not your only option for machine learning in iOS; you can find a comprehensive list of the available tools in the (continuously updated) [Machine Learning for iOS](http://alexsosn.github.io/ml/2015/11/05/iOS-ML.html) page (although, from a quick scan, I could not locate DBSCAN clustering there, either).

Comment: "in fact, it is not even recommended" - this statement, in my opinion, is too strong. Core ML is definitely the simplest way to run pre-trained models IF you don't need to train them on the device and IF there is a converter for your model.

Comment: @AlexanderSosnovshchenko agree - statement removed (it was a later add-on, actually).

Answer (score 0):

There is a [DBSCAN in Turicreate](https://github.com/apple/turicreate/blob/3e30d61110348db76223a18278ec8c7e0bed186f/userguide/clustering/dbscan.md). Turicreate [supports conversion to coreml](https://github.com/apple/turicreate) for [some models](https://apple.github.io/turicreate/docs/userguide/deployment/introduction.html), but not DBSCAN so far. ;(

You also probably can replace DBSCAN with some other clustering algorithm available in [dlib](http://dlib.net/ml.html) or [OpenCV](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/core/doc/clustering.html). They both can be compiled for an iOS project:

- [dlib](http://prabhu.xyz/2017/05/29/getting-started-with-dlib-on-ios.html)
- [OpenCV](https://cocoapods.org/pods/OpenCV)

Besides, DBSCAN is a pretty common algorithm. A brief [search over Github](https://github.com/search?l=C&q=dbscan&type=Repositories&utf8=%E2%9C%93) gives 56 repos in C++ and 9 C implementations (if you want Swift-compatibility).

Comment: A converter is a necessary but not a sufficient condition; in other words, since CoreML does not support clustering models, you cannot use the Turi Create converter to convert such a model to CoreML. And the dlib & OpenCV libraries are included in the link I gave in my answer.

Comment: @desertnaut, you are right, it rises ``AttributeError: 'DBSCANModel' object has no attribute 'export_coreml'``. Thank you for referring to my list, I just thought it might be helpful to have direct links to clustering algorithms and how to compile them for iOS as an addition.